# Multiple GPT ads in same page display only once

Tags: javascript, wordpress, ads, google-ads-api, google-ad-manager

i need display multiple ads on one page with this code:

```
<script async src="https://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/tag/js/gpt.js"></script>
<div id="gpt-passback650x250">
<script>
window.googletag = window.googletag || {cmd: []};
googletag.cmd.push(function() {
googletag.defineSlot('/162717810/xxxxx/650x250', [650, 250], 'gpt- 
passback650x250').addService(googletag.pubads());
googletag.enableServices();
googletag.display('gpt-passback650x250');
});
</script>
</div>
```

If i use this code twice or more on page, i get error: **Exception in queued GPT command TypeError: Cannot read property 'addService' of null**

Code must be same, customer want paste it to page via shortcode in cms. How to solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you put this:

```html
<script>
    window.googletag = window.googletag || {cmd: []};
    googletag.cmd.push(function() {
    googletag.defineSlot('/162717810/xxxxx/650x250', [650, 250], 'gpt-passback650x250').addService(googletag.pubads());
    googletag.enableServices();
    googletag.display('gpt-passback650x250');
    });
</script>
```

...before `</body>`, and this:

```html
<div id="gpt-passback650x250"></div>
```

...in every place you'd like to have ads?

Comment: Ads not display, in console i see error: Exception in queued GPT command TypeError: Cannot read property 'addService' of null
.

Comment: Do you see it if you place it only once, but as I explained?

Comment: Yes, if i remove every other ads from body, then i see it

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23236177/multiple-gpt-ads-in-same-page-with-same-ad-size-not-working

Comment: Still there is problem, i cant use different ID to body, because it should be in shortcode as one script

Comment: Then, I'm afraid, it's impossible task to do. You'll have to define different slots for GPTs, even though they can display the same ad.